# Image upload filter for PHP

Tags: php, file, validation, image

I am trying to improve my file upload handler filter.

### Environment

Since any client-side validation is easily circumvented, there is none in this code, for ease of testing. Not even an `accept="image/*"` on the `<input>` element. Production code will include some client side validation.

The upload handler is set up to first check that the standard php file upload criteria are met, and then goes on to validate that the upload file is an image and can be saved.

The Error handler is simplified

### Inspiration

I realized that my handler was vulnerable after completing [the upload vulnerabilities room in tryhackme](https://tryhackme.com/room/uploadvulns) since I originally only checked the extension and the mime type.

### Known possible pitfalls:

- non-image files like`.php` can still be uploaded with null char in name  `.php%00.png` with a spoofed header (e.g. `image/png` instead of `application/x-php`), but must have correct magic number.
- No check of whether the header matches the extension.

  - Fix1: scan for strings like `/bin/bash` and `<?php`?
  - check for null bytes in file names?

I put the code on [github](https://github.com/JoSSte/phpFileUploadHandler) as well...

```php
function is_image($filename) {
    // PNG, GIF, JFIF JPEG, EXIF JPEF (respectively)
    $allowed = array('89504E47', '47494638', 'FFD8FFE0', 'FFD8FFE1');

    $handle = fopen($filename, 'r');
    $bytes = strtoupper(bin2hex(fread($handle, 4)));
    fclose($handle);

    return in_array($bytes, $allowed);
}


$resize = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "resize", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$resize = (boolean) $resize;
//flag to indicate whether we would have saved the file...
$file_ok = false;
$preliminary_check = true;

//Preliminary check of basic PHP file handling
if ($_FILES["inageFile"]["error"] != 0) {
    switch ($_FILES["inageFile"]["error"]) {
        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE: //1
            error_log("File is too big. uploaded: " . $_FILES["inageFile"]["size"] . ")");
            $preliminary_check = false;
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE: //2
            error_log("Form is too big, " . $_FILES["inageFile"]["size"] . ")");
            $preliminary_check = false;
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL: //3
            error_log("Partial Error");
            $preliminary_check = false;
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE: //4
            error_log("No file uploaded");
            $preliminary_check = false;
            break;
        default:
            error_log("Unknown error " . $_FILES["inageFile"]["error"]);
            $preliminary_check = false;
            break;
    }
}

//if no errors, continue
if ($preliminary_check) {
    echo "PASSED preliminary check\n";
    if (substr($_FILES["inageFile"]["type"], 0, 6) == "image/") {
        if (is_image($_FILES["inageFile"]["tmp_name"])) {
            $im["filename"] = str_replace(" ", "-", $_FILES["inageFile"]["name"]); //replace spaces with hyphens
            $im["size"] = $_FILES["inageFile"]["size"];
            list($im["width"], $im["height"], $im["type"], $tempattr) = getimagesize($_FILES["inageFile"]["tmp_name"]);
            $im["type"] = $_FILES["inageFile"]["type"];
            if (!file_exists($uploadfile)) {
                error_log($_FILES["inageFile"]["name"] . " will not overwrite existing Logo. Would be saved.");
                //if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["inageFile"]["tmp_name"], $uploadfile)) {
                error_log($_FILES["inageFile"]["name"] . " has been confirmed to be an image and would have been saved on the server.");
                $file_ok = true;
            //} else {
            //    error_log("Error in file upload. " . $_FILES["inageFile"]["tmp_name"] . " cannot be moved to $uploadfile");
            //}
            } else {
                error_log("filename exists already");
            }
        } else{
            error_log($_FILES["inageFile"]["type"] . " does not match magic number");    
        } 
    } else {
        error_log("Mime/type is not an image - received: " . $_FILES["inageFile"]["type"]);
    }

    if($file_ok) {
        echo "FILE WOULD HAVE BEEN UPLOADED AND SAVED";
    }else {
        echo "FAILED image check";
    }
} else {
    echo "FAILED preliminary check";
}
```

Comment: I fail to see where do you checking the extension. Also, I'd like to see how that try to hack me thing is hacked with the extension check in place.

Comment: oh good point. apparently my weeding out of non-relevant code removed the extension check.

Comment: `fUpload.php%00.png` would be matched to a png file, but when writing the file some OSes will see the null byte as a string terminator, saving the file as `fUpload.php` which will then be callable.

Answer (score 3):

## Avoid pitfalls using PHP extensions

It is good to be aware of the pitfalls like users attempting to upload non-image files. In order to avoid them PHP extensions like [fileinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.installation.php) offers [`finfo_open()`](https://www.php.net/finfo_open)  and [the Exif extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.exif.php) offers [`exif_imagetype()`](https://www.php.net/exif_imagetype) - used in [this code to check if an uploaded file is an image](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/239789/120114).

## Other review points

### boolean type casting can be done when assigning initial value

> ```
> $resize = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "resize", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
> $resize = (boolean) $resize;
> ```

The cast can be done during the assignment from the function call:

```
$resize = (boolean) filter_input(INPUT_POST, "resize", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Also note that `boolean` is an alias of [`bool`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)<sup>[1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting)</sup> so it could be simplified to not use the alias:

```
$resize = (bool) filter_input(INPUT_POST, "resize", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

### Variable assignment is repetitive across `cases` in `switch` statement.

Inside the `switch` statement every `case` as well as the `default` includes:

> ```
>         $preliminary_check = false;
> ```

Thus that line can be pulled out of the `switch` statement and placed anywhere inside the conditional block `if ($_FILES["inageFile"]["error"] != 0) {`. Then all cases within the `switch` statement just have a call to `error_log()` before `break`. One could simplify that block using a [`match` statement](https://php.net/match).

### Prefer strict equality checks

As explained near the end of [this review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/289223/120114) it is wise to use strict equality operators like [`===`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) instead of `==` which uses type juggling.

This conditional:

> ```
> if (substr($_FILES["inageFile"]["type"], 0, 6) == "image/") {
> ```

Can be updated to

```
if (substr($_FILES["inageFile"]["type"], 0, 6) === "image/") {
```

because [`substr()`](https://www.php.net/substr) returns a string<sup>[1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php#refsect1-function.substr-description)</sup>.

Answer (score 1):

One way to be almost 100% secure against upload vulnerabilities is to convert the image yourself, maybe using a libary like [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php).

That way it would be very difficult to add code to the file that actually could be executed.

Comment: Time to learn about EXIF